# How best to subclass NSManagedObject to provide a set of core methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, refactoring

I am working on a typical IOS app that implements a Core Data model and I am using XCode to generate the base set of NSManagedObjects for each entity in the model.

Typical Example, nothing special here:

```
//
//  ContactKey.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class ContactAttribute;

@interface ContactKey : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * keyDescription;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * keyName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *rContactAttribute;
@end

@interface ContactKey (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addRContactAttributeObject:(ContactAttribute *)value;
- (void)removeRContactAttributeObject:(ContactAttribute *)value;
- (void)addRContactAttribute:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeRContactAttribute:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

I have created a data model management class that 'knows about' the managed entities that the app is using. A snippet of its header looks like this:

```
#pragma mark Action

- (Annotation *) newAnnotation;
- (BOOL) addAnnotation:(Annotation *)newAnnotation;
- (BOOL) deleteAnnotation:(Annotation *)entry;
- (NSArray *) findAnnotations:(Annotation *)withMatchCriteria;
- (NSArray *) findAnnotations;
- (void) dumpAnnotations;

#pragma mark Appointment

- (Appointment *) newAppointment;
- (BOOL) addAppointment:(Appointment *)newAppointment;
- (BOOL) deleteAppointment:(Appointment *)entry;
- (NSArray *) findAppointments:(Appointment *)withMatchCriteria;
- (NSArray *) findAppointments;
- (void) dumpAppointments;
```

Besides this leading to a lot of repetition, it's not proper object design. I realize I need to address each entity as its own object.

If I were doing this by hand, I would create a subclass of NSManagedObject that implements my core methods, then subclass this for each entity so I could add the entity specific methods I want.

As you know, each time that you modify the model and regenerate the managed entities XCode will overwrite the files, so this is not a viable solution.

What is the best approach to refactoring this code into individual managed entities that still allows XCode to regenerate the entity definitions as necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique is to completely separate the domain/semantic models from the Core Data object graph and storage by subclassing. The superclass deals with your CoreData stuffs, and the important or interesting domain methods are added to the subclass ... but it sounds like you already know all this! There are tools that can assist you.

[mogenerator](http://rentzsch.github.io/mogenerator/) ([github repo](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator)) can be used to managed this process. For a one-time, short setup, it integrates to your build, detects additions and changes to your models, and generates all the backing models for you (e.g. Animal model yields _Animal auto generated backing class with Core Data helpers and whatnot) and if it doesn't exist yet, it will generate a stub file for the subclass (e.g. Animal model yields Animal class). You then configure your source control to ignore the backing files, and commit the subclasses / domain-ish classes.

Frankly, I love mogenerator. Rewriting all those defaults accessors and helpers is neither fun nor interesting for me.

Comment: I just added mogenerator to my project and it's exactly what I was looking for. I posted the question expecting that XCode experts would point out the IDE features that I missed. This is better.

Comment: Marked this as accepted because I already have it working. Thanks!

Comment: After 4 days of using mogenerator and MagicRecord, I am happily refactoring my entities without worrying about the entity regeneration piece. I modify my schema, remake the mogenerator project and continue on. Takes about 2 minutes to update now. I can't endorse this solution enough.